# Last item in a template range

Tags: go, go-templates

Given the template:

```
{{range $i, $e := .SomeField}}
        {{if $i}}, {{end}}
        $e.TheString
{{end}}
```

This can output:

```
one, two, three
```

If, however, I want to output:

```
one, two, and three
```

I'd need to know which is the last element in the range above.

I can set a variable that holds the length of the array `.SomeField`, but that will always be 3, and the `$i` value above will only ever get to 2. And you can't perform arithmetic in templates from what I've seen.

Is detecting the last value in a template range possible? Cheers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant solution but it's the best I could find:

http://play.golang.org/p/MT91mLqk1s

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "text/template"
)

var fns = template.FuncMap{
    "last": func(x int, a interface{}) bool {
        return x == reflect.ValueOf(a).Len() - 1
    },
}


func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("abc").Funcs(fns).Parse(`{{range  $i, $e := .}}{{if $i}}, {{end}}{{if last $i $}}and {{end}}{{$e}}{{end}}.`))
    a := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, a)
}
```

**Note:** You can also do it without reflect using the `len` function (credit to Russ Cox):
http://play.golang.org/p/V94BPN0uKD

c.f.

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/yRXHSCjVAcM
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/XBScetK-guk/Bh7ZFz6R3wQJ
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/mqRbR7AFJj0

Comment: Thanks, although I was looking for something more elegant, this does seem to be the way to do it currently. I hope the golang team fix this infelicity at some point. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

We had same problem today when working with format in docker inspect command.
The easiest way to get the last element without patching Docker was (the expression has been split into lines for ease of reading):

```
{{ $image := "" }}
{{ range split .ContainerImageName "/" }}
    {{ $image = . }}{{ end }}
{{ index (split $image ":") 0 }}
```

So in our case, we needed the image name without registry address and version.
For example, image name like *registry.domain.local/images/nginx:latest* becomes *nginx*.

P.S: You need Go >= 1.11 to do the job (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10608)

P.P.S: The question was about Go template but for those who had same problems with Docker here the configuration examples:

1) Using Go template in `daemon.json`

`cat /etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
    "log-driver": "syslog",
    "log-opts": {
        "syslog-address": "udp://127.0.0.1:20627",
        "tag": "{{ $image :=  \"\" }}{{ range split .ContainerImageName \"/\" }}{{ $image = . }}{{ end }}{{ index (split $image \":\") 0 }}/{{.Name}}"
}
```

2) Using Go template with `-f` option:

```sh
docker inspect \
  -f '{{ $image := "" }}{{ range split .Config.Image "/" }}{{ $image = . }}{{ end }}{{ index (split $image ":") 0 }}' \
  <container>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this and solved it by adding an `isLast` helper function. It does require computing the length outside the helper, but it's a bit easier to read.

```
var helpers template.FuncMap = map[string]interface{}{
    "isLast": func(index int, len int) bool {
        return index+1 == len
    },
}
```

Which is used like:

```
{{$lenMyList := len .MyList}}
{{range $index, $item := .MyList}}
    <div>
        {{.SomeItemProp}}
        {{if (isLast $index $lenMyList)}}
            Last Item
        {{end}}
    </div>
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more elegant solution, avoids calling `len` or `sub`/`add` on every iteration:

https://go.dev/play/p/oRznNPw-YCr

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

var fns = template.FuncMap{
    "eq": func(x, y interface{}) bool {
        return x == y
    },
    "sub": func(y, x int) int {
        return x - y
    },
}

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("abc").Funcs(fns).Parse(`{{$last := (len . | sub 1)}}{{range  $i, $e := .}}{{if $i}}, {{end}}{{if eq $i $last}}and {{end}}{{$e}}{{end}}.`))
    a := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, a)
}
```